# Is possible PHP array id that not exist to be 0?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that can have a key `"d"` or not. The values associated with `"d"` comes from a mysql query. I don't want to show `"d"`'s value when it is

1. `NULL`
2. `"NULL"`
3. `""`
4. less than `0`

So I have this scenario:

```
// should show
$a = array("a"=>1,"b"=>NULL,"c"=>"zzz");
if ($a["d"] >= 0) {
  echo "show";
}

// should show
$a = array("a"=>1,"b"=>NULL,"c"=>"zzz","d"=>NULL);
if ($a["d"] >= 0) {
  echo "show";
}
```

It seems that php is recognizing `NULL` as `0` when `"d"=>NULL`. What is the best way to test those conditions without using `array_key_exists`?

Comment: try `$a["d"] > 0 || $a["d"] === 0`

Comment: `if (!empty($a["d"]) && $a["d"] !== 'NULL') && $a["d"] > 0)`

Comment: if ( ! empty($a["d"]) && $a["d"] => 0) {
 // do stuff
}

Comment: Hi King this works. But what happend whit "d" in the first case? Maybe it returns FASE (0) and if condition recognize like zero?

Comment: The `$a["d"] > 0` returns true only when `$a["d"]` is a positive number while the second just handles the case when it's the number `0` (strictly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you think php is interpreting the value as `0` is because when you do the comparison, you're using `>=`.

`>=` will typecast the left value to the type of the right-side value. So the comparison actually looks more like

```
((int) $a["d"]) >= 0
```

and null, when cast to an int, is 0.

you can also check for the existence of that array index using

```
isset($a['d'])
```

or

```
empty($a['d'])
```

This is the downside of having a loosely typed language, it gets confusing if you don't fully understand whats goin on. [check this out for a bunch more information](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Comment: castis is referring to the distinction between a "loose" comparison and a "strict" comparison.  Consider looking at [PHP's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) on the matter to learn more on how this works in various scenarios.  Many languages, PHP included, treat non-zero values in loose comparisons as "truthy."

Comment: Yes, this is the problem. Php treat NULL as zero. Even if you do this `ceil("abc") // float 0` It returns a zero. It seems the best practice to test if a variable is zero is `!is_null($var)&&$var===0` , in this case

Comment: @igoralves1 using strict comparison, that's not true. That means once you use `===` instead of `==`, `0` is the only value of `$var` if `$var === 0` returns true.

Comment: PHP does not treat null as zero. PHP treats null as null until you typecast it in the middle of a comparison. `ceil("abc")` returns zero because it casts the string you passed in to a float.

Answer (score 0):

[isset](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.isset.php) is your friend

```
<?php

$ar_list = array(
    array('d' => null),
    array('d' => 0),
    array('d' => 12),
);

foreach ($ar_list as $ar) {
    if (isset($ar['d']) && $ar['d'] >= 0) {
        echo "{$ar['d']}\n";
    };
};
```

The above example will output:

```
0
12
```